# Connect using FTP through another remote server

Tags: ssh, ftp

------------ **Setup**   ------------
**MyMachine**: My Machine is on a dynamic IP. This is a Windows Machine

**MyServer**: My Server has a static IP and MyMachine can connect to MyServer directly via SSH without any issue. This is an Ubuntu Server.

**RemoteServer**: Remote server provides FTP access to the MyServer IP and I can FTP to RemoteServer only when I take remote control of MyServer. I don't know what server it is, I think its Windows based.

----------- **Requirement** ------------
I do not want to take remote control of MyServer everytime I have to FTP something to Remote Server. I can certainly use SSH from MyMachine to MyServer and then FTP via command line, but I am looking for a GUI tool like WinSCP or Filezilla. I want to use WinSCP/Filezilla and FTP to RemoteServer directly from MyMachine.

I tried setting up VPN connection between MyMachine and MyServer but that did not help. Someone gave an idea about using proxy server but I am not convinced that it would work.

Can anyone guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Later versions of OpenSSH can act as a SOCKS proxy.

On MyMachine install some version of the OpenSSH client (there are several available precompiled from the internet) and then run:

```
ssh MyServer -D6789
```

Then use some FTP client supporting SOCKS as, for instance, Firefox.

Obviously, you have to configure it to use the SOCKS proxy listening at port 6789 for FTP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Let me try my hands on this.

Comment: Is there a  possibility to guide further on this. Using Putty (Connection > Proxy > SOCKS4) I can connect to MyServer. Before connecting to MyServer, I shall have OpenSSH and SOCKS configured on it. But after doing all this, how to use FTP Client is not clear to me.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.adamfowlerit.com/2013/01/05/using-firefox-with-a-putty-ssh-tunnel-as-a-socks-proxy)!